# Fortran variable type defaults - origin

Tags: programming, fortran

In older versions of Fortran, e.g. 77, variables did not need to be declared.  If the name starts with I, J, K, L, M, or N then it would be assumed to be an INTEGER.  Otherwise, it would be assumed to be REAL (float).

This might still be true of more recent versions but I have no experience of them and this is a retro group so I am not asking about them.

My question is on the origin of the convention.  I have heard one explanation that I and N are the first two letters of INTEGER.

However, similar habits are common in maths.  i, j, k, l, m, and n are very popular for integers whereas as x, y, and z are very popular for real numbers.  Which influenced the other?  Did existing maths habits influence Fortran or did Fortran influence maths?

Comment: Re. 'recent' versions (90/95/03/08/15): The default implicit types for variables have not changed. They can be adjusted using the implicit statement, or switched off entirely with implicit none. I suspect most Fortran users put implicit none at the top of every program unit, since implicit typing doesn't make much sense unless programs are entered on punch cards!

Comment: @IanThompson Thanks.  I think that IMPLICIT has been in the language for a long time.  It sounds familiar.  A quick search suggests that it was in FORTRAN 77.  Though it seems that the NONE option came later.

Comment: Indeed, the facility to mess around with implicit types (making them even more confusing and error prone) was introduced in FORTRAN 77. Implicit none was introduced in Fortran 90. Curiously, implicit typing can be used for derived types (also introduced in 90). Why anyone thought that was a good idea is beyond me.

Comment: @IanThompson Today, I prefer languages in which variables must be explicitly declared but, way back in the days when Fortran 77 was current, implicit declarations seemed like a good idea.

Comment: I can understand why they would be convenient when using punch cards, but why the feature was extended to derived types in F90 is beyond me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The use of such letters was common in mathematics long before programming existed. *x*, *y*, *z* were used as variables [by Descartes in 1637](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(mathematics)#Genesis_and_evolution_of_the_concept); in his framework, *a*, *b*, *c* and other letters towards the start of the alphabet represented known values, letters towards the end of the alphabet represented unknown values. The use of *i*, *j* etc. doesn’t go quite that far back, but it was common at least for summation and other such operations, where the variables represent indices.

[The original FORTRAN paper](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Fortran/102679231.05.01.acc.pdf) doesn’t give any specific arguments for the FORTRAN pattern, which is more than convention: variables in FORTRAN O could be of two types, fixed point (with a one- or two-symbol name starting with *i*, *j*, *k*, *l*, *m*, or *n*), or floating point (with a one- or two-symbol naming starting with any other character of the alphabet). [Knuth notes](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/stanford/cs_techReports/STAN-CS-76-562_EarlyDevelPgmgLang_Aug76.pdf) that “the names of variables were restricted to be at most *two* characters long at this time; but this in itself was an innovation, FORTRAN being the first language in which a variable’s name could be larger than one letter, contrary to established mathematical conventions”. As can be seen in the rest of that paper, early programming languages closely followed mathematical representation, which explains the influence of the latter on the former.

There has been some amount of influence of computer programming notation on mathematical notation since then though; for example, some mathematical papers use words as variable names rather than single letters.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew that mostly maths syntax influenced programming language syntax but I was not so sure about the association of I through N with integers.  Of course, one major difference is the use of =.  x = x + 1 is nonsense in most areas of maths.  I liked Algol for that reason as it reserved = for a more mathematical use.

Comment: Over in maths, p and q are very popular for integers e.g. an archetypal rational number is p/q.  Yet they are real by default in Fortran.  Not surprising really, maths is too large and varied to expect an exact match.  This question was motivated by one in the math SE in which someone commented that he preferred to reserve i, j, k for integers.  Of course, another common use for i in maths is sqrt(-1).  Which reminds me that Fortran is the only language that I know with a built-in complex type.

Comment: Both C and C++ have included complex types for a long time, but for whatever reason they've never seemed very popular.

Comment: @badjohn Python has a built-in complex type. And uses j instead of i in complex literals for the imaginary part. I guess because that's more common in physics. j can be used as name though.  As in `j = 42+23j`, which assigns a complex with 42 as real part and 23 as imaginary part to the name `j`.

Comment: @supercat It's over 10 years since I did any serious C or C++.  Is complex actually a type comparable to double or just a class?  At least in C++ (unlike Java), you can override operators and use traditional arithmetic notation for classes.

Comment: @BlackJack Thanks.  Python has got on to my "need to look at" list but not yet my "have looked at list".  I am used to j in electrical engineering but many branches of physics use i e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation.  j as a variable and the imaginary unit - deliberate obfuscation?

Comment: @badjohn Just about every language used in maths or science has complex arithmetic built in, including Ada, APL, C, C++, Common Lisp, D, F#, Fortran, Go, Haskell, IDL, J, Julia, Maple, Mathematica, Matlab/Octave, Maxima, Nim, OCaml, PARI/GP, Perl, PL/I, Python, R, Racket, Ruby and TCL. (Many of these languages do simply define the type as a class/ADT in their standard library, but don't really have a fundamental distinction between such types and “true built-in” types like `double`.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have been doing Java and business programming for too long so my knowledge of other languages is very rusty.  The last time that I did C++, it did not even have a String type.  The attitude was: if you want a string type then write one yourself.

Comment: In a more retro-vein.  One ancient dialect of Basic that I used had matrix support built in.  There was an instruction  MAT rather like LET except that the variables could be matrices.

Comment: @badjohn: At least in C, complex is a built-in primitive type (C doesn't have classes).  Support for complex numbers, like support for variable-length arrays, was added in the C99 standard, but they're such widely popular features that a lot of programmers aren't even aware of them.

Comment: @badjohn: `std::string` was defined in the original C++98 standard and was well established in 1993 when I first used C++.  I don't really think it's fair to call a language without `std::string` "C++"

Comment: My last serious C++ programming was early 90s.  Maybe we were using old compilers.  The compiler on our HP system still was a preprocessor for a C compiler.

Comment: @badjohn Yeah, I have an electrical engineering degree, so we were taught about EE’s particular usage of *j* for the imaginary number (since by convention, *i* was used for AC current and *I* was used for DC current). So far as I have seen, and certainly as it was presented to me, this usage is unique to EE, which implies someone writing up Python is from that area. That, or they were even more worried about confusion with `i` in indices than they were `j`.

Comment: @KRyan Oddly, I learned sqrt(-1) first as j.  I did A level further maths in the UK and, at the time (long ago), our books used j.  The electrical engineering motivation was briefly mentioned.  Later at university, I had to get used to i.  I wonder what they use in school today or even if they still teach complex numbers in school.

Comment: @badjohn I certainly learned complex numbers long before enrolling in any degree; in New York at least, the imaginary number was only referred to as *i*. That was probably fifteen years ago, but I highly doubt it’s changed. I only heard about *j* in college, and then only in EE (we still used *i* in our physics courses and our non-electrical engineering courses).

Comment: @KRyan Our school courses often make rather quirky decisions on standards not just j versus i.  When assisting children with school work, I sometimes struggle because they have been taught some odd definition and led to believe that it is the only one.  I guess that the idea is to not confuse them with multiple definitions but the cost is that they have to do some unlearning later.

Comment: At school (in the UK in the 80's) I was taught both i and j for complex numbers. All the maths teachers used i but said "you should really use j". In physics I was taught j partly because complex numbers come up mostly when talking about AC circuits. When I started my maths course at University, I was told in no uncertain terms that it's i: "we invented it, those engineers can take a running jump".

Comment: @badjohn - interesting.  A level maths/further maths in my time period (early 90s) was dominated by the textbook set known by its authors names Bostok & Chandler ... and they definitely used "i".  By my understanding, revisions of the same books are still in common use.

Comment: Back on the topic -- I've always assumed that the use of i in Fortran (and in the kind of maths it derives from) is motivated as an abbreviation of "index", and following letters are used as part of the general convention of moving on to the next letter if the obvious one is already in use ... and potentially that 'n' is chosen as the end point as an abbreviation of 'number'.  But I've no particular reason to assume these things, it just *seems* right to me.